# Singular homology: Change of coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a map of topological spaces which induces isomorphisms $H_*(f;\mathbb{Z})$ on singular homology with $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients. Show that $f$ induces isomorphisms $H_*(f;\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z})$ on singular homology with $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

What's the general approach to proofing something like that? I don't know any algebraic tools to change the ring of singular homology.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider the universal coefficient theorem.

Comment: I know no algebraic topology. But, it sounds like you want to show that if $f$ induces an isomorphism  of two long exact sequences of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, then $f$ induces an isomorphism of the sequences as $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$-modules. If so, then I would think to tensor with $(--)\otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$. A google search gave me [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633592/the-singular-homology-and-cohomology-of-a-topological-space-with-coefficients-in).

Comment: We didn't cover the universal coefficient theorem yet, there has to be another way. What do I have to tensor to get the desired result?

Comment: You don't need tensor products or the universal coefficient theorem for this. Hint: $f$ induces an iso in $H_*(\_;R)$ for a commutative ring $R$ iff $\tilde{H}(cone(f),R)$ vanishes. Consider the self chain map on the singular chain complex of $cone(f)$ which is given by multiplying the coefficients with $k$. As soon as $k\neq 0$ (this case is trivial) this is injective and it's cokernel computes the $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ homology. Now take a look at the LES of this SES. The same can be done with reduced homology, too.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot.